# Puppet - pass variable with a file create command

Tags: puppet

I need a way to pass a given variable - lets say thearch - to several different files within a given class. I need to be able to state the contents of this variable for each file individually.

I have tried the following:

```
file { "xxx":
  thearch => "i386",
  path    => "/xxx/yyyy",
  owner   => root,
  group   => root,
  mode    => 644,
  content => template("module/test.erb"),
}
```

This doesn't pass this variable so I can use it with a <%=thearch%> statement within the erb file as I expect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ... and your erb file contains something like `<%= @thearch %>`? Just checking, your example lacks `@` from `<%=thearch%>` ...

Comment: I tried a couple variants, I'll double check that specifically.

Comment: Using the @ returns "Invalid parameter".

Comment: Strange. Have you read this? http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html

Comment: Repeatedly, unfortunately it doesn't seem to cover my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to wrap the file in a define that does take that parameter, so that it's available when the template is called, and then call that define. If a lot of the parameters are usually the same, set them as defaults while you're at it just to keep the code clean.

```
define thearch_file($thearch, $path, $owner = root, $group = root, $mode = 0644, $template = '/module/test.erb') {
  file { $name:
    path    => $path,
    owner   => $owner,
    group   => $group,
    mode    => $mode,
    content => template($template),
  }
}

thearch_file {
  "xxx":
    thearch => 'i386',
    path    => "/xxx/yyy";
  "yyy":
    thearch => 'x86_64',
    path    => "/xxx/zzz";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't define arbitrary meta parameters for the File resource like "thearch". The only meta parameters available are the ones [here.](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/type.html#file) You could use the existing architecture fact from the nodes which might give you the functionality you want.

```
<%= architecture %>
```

or perhaps

```
<% if architecture == 'i386' then -%>
  do some stuff
<% end-%>
```

Comment: That is kind of what I figured, however the architecture facts don't work in this situation (the given host is providing resources for multiple architectures).

Comment: You might want to create a new question explaining what you're trying to do. It isn't very clear from the above. I'd recommend a define in general, but it's not clear how you're deciding or why the current facts won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Arguments to a resource are not arbitrary values. You could do this, though:

```
thearch = "i386"
file { "xxx":
  path    => "/xxx/yyyy",
  owner   => root,
  group   => root,
  mode    => 644,
  content => template("module/test.erb"),
}
```